# iPhone touch event of two UIviews

Tags: iphone

I'm working on a very simple application for iPhone now. On some state, the application shows a table and a layer over it. the layer contains a background image and a button.

When clicking the button - nothing happens. instead - the table selected row is being triggered.

What am I doing wrong?

David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you remove the table view from the superview?

```
[viewWithTableInIt removeFromSuperview];
[theview addSubivew:viewWithBackgroundImageAndButton];
```

or if you need to keep the "layer" (I assume you mean a view) with the table in it as a subview, you could do

```
viewWithTableInIt.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Layers are for drawing, not handling events. To respond to touch events, you generally need to be a subclass of UIResponder (which CALayer is not). So, how have you put this layer over the UITableView? If it really is a CALayer, then this isn't going to work; you need to use a UIView. If it's really a UIView that you just called a layer, then provide some information about how you created the view. The most likely cause for a view to not respond is for `hitTest:withEvent:` to fail as described in the [UIView docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent:):

> This method ignores views that are hidden, that have disabled user interaction, or have an alpha level less than 0.1.